# Floor() function on a datetime - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, floor

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/639ec/2

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
ID INT,
OrderNo int,
DateReceived datetime
)

INSERT INTO TEST (ID,OrderNo,DateReceived)
VALUES ('1', '3454', '07-20-2018 00:00:00')
```

Query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime,
@FlooredStart datetime ,
@FlooredEnd datetime 

SET @StartDate = '07-20-18'
SET @EndDate = '07-20-18'
SET @FlooredStart  = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@startDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
SET @FlooredEnd = DATEADD(d, 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@endDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))

SELECT * FROM TEST 
WHERE DateReceived = @FlooredStart and DateReceived < @FlooredEnd
```

In my live version if the date received is left blank it defaults to the time 12:00:00AM of that day. So for this example if i search for orders on the 07-20-18 it wont return the order that was placed at 12:00:00AM of the 07-20-18.

So i figure to add >= to the clause

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime,
@FlooredStart datetime ,
@FlooredEnd datetime 

SET @StartDate = '07-20-18'
SET @EndDate = '07-20-18'
SET @FlooredStart  = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@startDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
SET @FlooredEnd = DATEADD(d, 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@endDate AS FLOAT)) AS 
DATETIME))

SELECT * FROM TEST 
-- WHERE DateReceived BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
WHERE DateReceived >= @FlooredStart and DateReceived < @FlooredEnd
```

Result:

```
| ID | OrderNo |         DateReceived |
|----|---------|----------------------|
|  1 |    3454 | 2018-07-20T00:00:00Z |
```

I was just wondering if i had this logic correct? And can anyone explain to me exactly what the floor() function is doing. I understand that its calculating the first day of year/month but is that needed here? I looked online and i could'nt find a definitive answer anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: if you want to compare dates only, use `date` parameters, not `datetime`. If you want to convert `datetime` fields to `date` use `cast(DateReceived as date)`. SQL Server is smart enough to convert the comparisons to range queries

Comment: Why in the world are you using FLOOR on a datetime??? That is a really bizarre way to strip off the time portion. Much easier (and intuitive) to convert to a date.

Comment: This code likely comes from someone originally working on SQL Server 2005 or earlier. Since SQL Server 2008 the `DATE` type exists and is much more convenient for "rounding to midnight". (Even before that, using `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` is more intuitive and more general than relying on `DATETIME`s conversion to `FLOAT`.)

Comment: I'm a little confused here. You seem to be saying that on your instance the values `20180720` and `2018-07-20T00:00:00` are not the same. This isn't the case: `SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(date,'20180720') = CONVERT(datetime2,'2018-07-20T00:00:00') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;` returns 1. If, however, you are working with times and dates, I prefer the `>=` and `<` method: `WHERE DatetimeColumn >= '20170720' AND DatetimeColumn < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '20170720')`. This also maintains SARGability, as `CONVERT(date,DatetimeColumn)` isn't SARGable.

Comment: It might be the case that @JeroenMostert mentioned. I just picked up this scenario. What is the best way too improve floor()

Comment: to try and explain this - DateTime is held in a format identical to a float, with the whole number part representing a day count since 1/1/1900 and the decimal part representing seconds (in some way).  Floor truncates down to the lowest whole number, so if you change to a float, apply FLOOR, then back to a datetime, you remove all the seconds into the day, making the time midnight.

Comment: in your example, you already have a time that is at midnight, so the FLOOR operation isn't doing anything.  Also you should prefer the ISO date format SET @StartDate = '20180720' avoids problems

Comment: @Larnu actually converting a datetime column to date is one of those oddball times that is actually SARGable but it isn't always a great idea. :) https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea

Comment: @SeanLange interesting, however, I can't say I'd ever trust that. One would *think* that `DATEADD(DAY, 1, DateColumn)` was SARGable too, but... >_<

Comment: That one makes sense that it isn't because it has to calculate the results of the function for every row. But I agree that I wouldn't trust it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `floor` to "truncate" the time part, use the date-only `date` type :

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20180720', @EndDate date='20180720'

SELECT * FROM TEST 
WHERE cast(DateReceived date) between @startdate and @enddate
```

or, for a single date only :

```
SELECT * FROM TEST 
WHERE cast(DateReceived date) = @startdate
```

Note that I'm using the unseparated date literal. This is the *only* unambiguous date format. The other unambiguous format is the full ISO8601 format for the datetime types. Two-digit years are just *begging* for incorrect interpretation way.

`cast(DateReceived date)` will convert the `datetime` values in `DateReceived` into `date` values. Usually, it's a *bad* idea to apply functions to fields because it prevents the query optimizer to use any indexes. SQL Server understands `cast( ... as date)` though and converts :

```
cast(DateReceived date) = @startdate
```

To a range query equivalent to `DateReceived between @startdate at 00:00 but before the next day at 00:00` , allowing it to use any indexes on `DateReceived`